# About java Timer

Tags: java, timer

I am doing some testing with Timer in java.

My program starts a Timer, then waits for 2 seconds, cancels the Timer and prints out the j variable.

However the Timer still runs even though I canceled it. Thanks.

```
public static Timer time;
public static int j=0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            testrun();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            time.cancel();
            System.out.println("timer stop");

            System.out.println(j);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void testrun()
    {
        time = new Timer();
        time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  for(int i = 0;i<100;i++){
                  System.out.println(i);
                  j++;
                  }

                  System.out.println("End timer");
              }
            }, 1000, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Timer.cancel() v/s TimerTask.cancel()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21492693/java-timer-cancel-v-s-timertask-cancel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `cancel` only aborts the timer - if the task has begun it will run to completion.

If you wish to abort the task you need to keep track of it and call it's `interrupt` method.

```
public static Timer time = new Timer();
public static Thread runningThread = null;
public static int j = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        testrun();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        time.cancel();
        System.out.println("timer stop");
        if (runningThread != null) {
            // Interrupt the thread.
            runningThread.interrupt();
        }
        System.out.println(j);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void testrun() {
    time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Catch the thread that is running my task.
            runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                j++;
            }

            System.out.println("End timer");
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to `Timer.cancel()` will stop any further scheduled but unexecuted tasks from being executed, but it won't interrupt a running task.

See the [Javadoc for `Timer.cancel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29) (emphasis mine):

> Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks. **Does not interfere with a currently executing task** (if it exists).